# Probability for normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> The speed of cars is represented as normal distribution $N(87;144)$. What is the probability that a randomly selected car has a speed that is least $100$ km/h?

My solution is:

For $x = 100: Z = (100 - 87)/ 12 = 1.083$
$P(Z>1.083) = 1 - 0.85993 = 0.14$
So, the answer is that the probability of randomly selected car has speed $100$ km/h or higher is about $14$%.

And my question: is that a correct solution or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps and reasoning are correct but pay attention to the wording of your final answer. You mentioned:

> $P(z>1.083) = 1 - 0.85993 = 0.14$ So, the answer is that the
> probability of randomly selected car has speed $100$ km/h or higher is
> about $14$%.

However that is not true, the probability is $0.14$ and not $14$% and that is what they asked for, the percentage is $14$%, remember that any probability must be between $0$ and $1$.